# C# equivalent of PHP openssl_public_decrypt

Tags: c#, php, encryption, cryptography

What is the C# equivalent of the PHP function `openssl_public_decrypt`?

I have tried using RSACryptoProvider, but api will not allow me to decrypt without a private key,

I need to create a hash of the provided data and then compare against the provided signature

in PHP

```
$key = openssl_get_publickey('provided_public_key'));
openssl_public_decrypt(base64_decode($_GET['signature']), $hashExpected, $key);
```

so my question is how to generated the hashExpected in c#?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one: the .NET Framework does not come with OpenSSL.

There is a wrapper for OpenSSL you can use from within .NET: http://openssl-net.sourceforge.net/ however it doesn't have a direct analog for `openssl_public_decrypt` as it provides a close wrapper.

.NET comes with the rich `System.Cryptography` namespace.

Looking at PHP's openssl source code (here: https://github.com/frice2014/php_source/blob/467ed5d6edff72219afd3e644516f131118ef48e/ext/openssl/php_openssl.c ) we see that `openssl_public_decrypt` calls `RSA_public_decrypt`, however this is an implementation detail. The documentation for PHP's `openssl_public_decrypt` function does not specify what algorithm it uses, so you cannot depend on data being read by other implementations of RSA, such as .NET's.

I'm assuming you're trying to write C# that is interopable with PHP, rather than outright replacing it. In which case I suggest changing your PHP implementation so you know **exactly** what crypto algorithms are in use (complete with any IV and cipher-block-mode), because without those you cannot get the two to reliably work together.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `openssl_public_decrypt` supports a multitude of algorithms. In the examples in the comments people are generally getting the public key from an X.509 cert via `openssl_get_publickey`. The X.509 cert would specify the algorithm the public key is using (probably RSA). The fourth parameter though makes me think that only RSA would be supported. Off hand I'm not sure of any other public key algorithms that support encryption (DSA and ECDSA just do signatures and that's it) but to my knowledge PKCS1 padding is RSA only. I don't know if it'd make sense for other algos.

Comment: @neubert FYI, openssl_public_decrypt is a poorly named function for verifying signature.

Comment: @jbtule - the function for verifying sigs is `openssl_verify`. http://php.net/openssl-public-decrypt says "`Decrypts data with public key`" That Oscar Cabrero is asking about `openssl_public_decrypt` when he's wanting to do signature verification just means that he's a little misinformed I think. But then again if he simply encrypted the hash then what he's doing would be correct.

Comment: @neubert it's a low level function, granted, but it's not really meant for decryption is my point, it's meant to implement signature verification.

Comment: I have tried using a third party library openssl with success, but cannot used use it in my project due to legal reasons, so @neubert , are you telling me that openssl_public_decrypt is equivalent as rsaCryptoProvider.VerifyHash or VerifyData? because I have tried both with no luck

Comment: OpenSSL is available under a BSD-style license, so you should be able to use it in your project.

Comment: @jbtule - maybe that's it's intention but it doesn't actually do any hashing or anything. See http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/interop.html (click on private_encrypt / public_decrypt) to see what it does.

Comment: @Oscar - I'm not familiar with C# but looking at the link I gave to jbtule may be of benefit to you too to see what it's doing beneath the surface. Good luck!